# How can we write Faraday's law if $\vec{E}$ is conservative?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, conservative-field

From multivariable calculus you can assure that the line integral of a conservative field around a closed loop is always going to be zero. It is well known that the electric field is a conservative field (or could we think of non-conservative electric fields?).

With that, the integral

$$\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$$

Should be zero (of course assuming conservative $\vec{E}$).

How can it make sense that

$$\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}=-\frac{d}{dt}\iint_\Sigma\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$$

By saying so, you are saying that the magnetic flux is invariable on time for any given situationsituation, and this is clearly false.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *not* well-known that $\vec{E}$ is a conservative field, because it's wrong. You should study the fundamental equations of electromagnetism, Maxwell's equations. One of those holds:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

As you can see, as soon as there's a time-dependent magnetic field, the electric field is no longer a conservative field.

This is precisely how the last equation from your post is derived.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This means that, when a change in magnetic field appears, we no longer can think of electric potential difference?

Comment: @rodryx11 Mostly yes. It is possible to re-define the electric potential after that, alongside the magnetic potential. But the traditional potentiel difference used in electricity has a limited validity.

Comment: @rodryx11 We can still think of potential difference, when this potential is defined in an agreed way, e.g. most usually the Coulomb potential. But this potential only reflects conservative part of electric field, not total field. For example, force acting on current is not, in general, just due to difference of potential, but also due to induced electric field.

Answer (score 2):

Simply note that $\mathbf{E}$ is not conservative in general. The actual relation is $$\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V-\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t},$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the magnetic [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential). The appearance of the extra magnetic vector potential term comes from the fact that $$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} \ne 0,$$ as given by Faraday's law. In order for $\mathbf{E}$ to be conservative, the fields have to be time-independent, which takes things back to electrostatics.

Comment: E can be conservative if only B is time-independent, but E is time-dependent. For example, system with constant current charging capacitor.